# products of two different i.i.d

Tags: probability

Suppose$\left \{ X_1,\dots,X_n  \right \}$  is a sequence of independent and identically distributed(i.i.d) random variables with finite expected value $E[X_i]=\mu _{x}$ and variance  $Var[X_i]=\sigma_x^{2}$. And $\left \{ \alpha _1,\dots,\alpha _n  \right \}$  is another sequence of i.i.d random variables with finite expected value $E[\alpha _i]=\mu _{\alpha }$ and variance  $Var[\alpha _i]=\sigma_\alpha ^{2}$,
$\alpha _i$ is independent of $X_i$,then for the sequence $\left\{\alpha_1X_1,\dots,\alpha_nX_n \right \}$,how can we prove $\alpha_iX_i$ is also i.i.d and caculate its expected value and variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $\alpha_1X_1,\ldots,\alpha_nX_n$ are independent, we can use the fact that functions of independent random vectors are also independent. As random vectors, $(\alpha_1,X_1),\ldots,(\alpha_n,X_n)$ are independent.

To show that they are identically distributed, we need to notice that we have the same function that maps $\alpha_i$ and $X_i$ to $\alpha_iX_i$. Since $\alpha_i$'s are identically distributed and $X_i$'s are identically distributed, so are $\alpha_iX_i$'s since we use the same function to map $\alpha_i$ and $X_i$ to $\alpha_iX_i$.

To calculate the expected value, we need to use the independence to obtain
$$
\operatorname E[\alpha_iX_i]=\operatorname E[\alpha_i]\operatorname E[X_i].
$$

The variance can be obtain in the following way
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\alpha_iX_i)=\operatorname E[(\alpha_iX_i)^2]-(\operatorname E[\alpha_iX_i])^2=\operatorname E[\alpha_i^2]\operatorname E[X_i^2]-(\operatorname E[\alpha_i]\operatorname E[X_i])^2.
$$

I hope this helps

Comment: This helps me.Thank you very much！

Comment: Could you give me the references of the theorems "functions of independent random vectors are also independent" and "same function maps identically distributed to identically distributed"?I'm hardly found the related information on the web.Thanks again.

Comment: @byzeng A reference of the first theorem is Theorem 11.3.1 [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4615-7676-1). It seems that the proof is left as an exercise but the proof for random vectors is essentially the same as for random variables which is discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/94872/46220). The statement and the proof of the second theorem is given [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1950-7) (see Theorem 1 on page 28).